# How to use existing mongodb collection in rails3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection in a mongodb imported from csv file, and I want to load that into my ruby-on-rails3.2.13 app to list the collections document in homepage.
I have used mongoid as an object document mapper.
Can anyone please tell me the process for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be plain and simple if I understood your question.

say you have a model that uses mongoid

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document
  #define fields here
end
```

then in controller

```
@records = Model.all
```

then you should get an array of records

Comment: if the answer above helps to find the solution then accept it. Or please mention the solution here. So that others who will see the question can get the actual answer. thanks for understanding :)